# Oracle to HBase: Pivot

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hbase, database-migration, nosql

I'm migrating from Oracle to HBase and need some help in a particular case.

The structure of my data that I've imported to HBase using Sqoop is something like this:

```
YEAR    MONTH   AMOUNT
2010    jan 100
2010    fev 200
2011    jan 50
2011    fev 100
```

Now I need to get this data in this structure:

```
YEAR    JAN FEV
2010    100 200
2011    50  100
```

Is there a way to do it? How?

Many thanks!

Luiz

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query option to import from a query instead of a table.
Then you can query the data using the pivot syntax.

Something like that:

```
sqoop import \
  --query 'select * from (select year, month, amount from myTable) pivot (sum(amount) for month in ('jan','fev'))'
```

Comment: this will have memory limitation for more number of columns

Comment: If the data is the same as he described, there will never be more than 12 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think pivoting is not supported in sqoop.You can write your own Map-Reduce program for bulk loading the data to HBase as per your requirement using HFileOutputFromat.More information about bulkloading can be found [here](http://hbase.apache.org/book/arch.bulk.load.html) and [here](https://github.com/jrkinley/hbase-bulk-import-example)

Comment: Thanks Sachin, I'll try to find out and hear moe about bulkloading.